# Bounding box not plotting for yolo v7 model training and conversion

Tags: yolov5, yolov7

yolo v7 small object detection

I trained a yolov7-tiny model post that I converted the weight file into open-vino and I used yolov5 proc with dlstreamer, its working for every model except the head model, as in the bounding boxes are not plotting properly. What could be the reason?
I tried with custom anchors also but result end up with same thing..